# Handling of blocking IO calls in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, reactive-programming, blocking

Please have a look at the following classes, which one is suggested and how they are different..?

```
// Approach 1
public class Test extends Controller {
    private final DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext;

    @Inject
    public Test(DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext) {
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Result> get() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return io().thenApply(Results::ok);
    }

    public CompletableFuture<String> io() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "io";
        }, executionContext);

    }
}
```

```
//Approach 2
public class Test extends Controller {
    private final DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext;

    @Inject
    public Test(DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext) {
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
    }

    public Result get() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        return Results.ok(io());
    }

    public String io() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "io";
        }, executionContext).join();

    }
}
```

I want to understand how to properly handle blocking IO calls.
Can someone explain how Play framework uses Completable Future, in my point of view it's still blocking and does not make much sense and making my code deal with CompletableFuture which itself is horrible.

Answer (score 1):

`Play is new to me, I want to understand how to properly handle blocking IO calls.`

Hi! Great question. I've been using Play! for a while now and I think you've stumbled on one of the most complicated questions that Play! has to offer. Lets use the official Play! docs to answer your question:

> The default configuration is tuned for asynchronous controllers. In other words, the application code should avoid blocking in controllers, i.e., having the controller code wait for an operation. Common examples of such blocking operations are JDBC calls, streaming API, HTTP requests and long computations. [[1]](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaAsync)

So to answer your question: easy don't use blocking calls at all. :) Keep reading if you still want to do blocking calls.

`Can someone explain how Play framework uses Completable Future, in my point of view it's still blocking and does not make much sense and making my code deal with CompletableFuture which itself is horrible.`

Both of the examples you provided are indeed blocking. There is one slight difference between them. The `get()` method with the CompletableFuture will exit immediately and the `get()` method without will not exit. It will wait for the blocking call to complete.
The first one will release the Play! resource to do other things, like handle other requests.

Since you are doing blocking calls you will probably need to devise a strategy on how you want to handle them:

> Play Framework is, from the bottom up, an asynchronous web framework. Streams are handled asynchronously using iteratees. Thread pools in Play are tuned to use fewer threads than in traditional web frameworks, since IO in play-core never blocks.
>
> Because of this, if you plan to write blocking IO code, or code that could potentially do a lot of CPU intensive work, you need to know exactly which thread pool is bearing that workload, and you need to tune it accordingly. Doing blocking IO without taking this into account is likely to result in very poor performance from Play Framework, for example, you may see only a few requests per second being handled, while CPU usage sits at 5%. In comparison, benchmarks on typical development hardware (eg, a MacBook Pro) have shown Play to be able to handle workloads in the hundreds or even thousands of requests per second without a sweat when tuned correctly. [[2]](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ThreadPools)

Again the docs are here to help you devise this strategy: [Best practices for ThreadPools](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ThreadPools#Best-practices)

If your app is super high synchronous you can just forget the CompletableFuture approach and use the one described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ThreadPools#Highly-synchronous

Comment: Your answer is helpful and clears some of the doubts. However I got this in the documentation https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaAsync#Actions-are-asynchronous-by-default. This confuses me even more. Even when Controller is returning completablefuture and there is a blocking call down the line, isnt it still going to be blocking for the calling thread?

Comment: If you have a blocking call there is absolutely nothing that Play! can do to make it non blocking. The only thing you can actually do is devise a strategy on where to proccess the blocking call. This article has really cleared up things for me: https://blog.redelastic.com/work-stealing-what-makes-the-play-framework-fast-4b71fa7758d5 At the end there is a section which lists modes of concurrency. In your case it's Asynchronous and blocking.